# How to add flowtype to an ejected create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, flowtype, yarnpkg

We are working on a previously ejected `create-react-app` and now want to add flowtype.

We have followed the guide at: https://flow.org/en/docs/tools/create-react-app/

Should that work for an ejected app?

This has unfortunately caused the webpack-dev server launched with `yarn start` to stop automatically reloading on file updates.

Additionally, after adding `// @flow` to some files there is no output or indication of flow enforcing type checking.

Will we need to manually update the webpack configs?

Heres the `package.json` scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "yarn build-client && yarn build-server",
    "build-client": "node scripts/build.js",
    "build-server": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config ./config/webpack.server.config.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
  },
```

The output for running `yarn start` is:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view cra in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.65:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.
```

Comment: No output?  Or no errors? Can you post your configs and output of running flow?

Comment: @DaveMeehan by "output of running flow"  you mean output of `yarn start` or `node scripts/start.js` ?

Comment: Whatever method you use to run the flow binary.  Post your package.json (scripts section) if you're not sure

Comment: @DaveMeehan added scripts and out put examples

Comment: You haven't setup flow yet, nor modified your test script to run flow.  `yarn start` is running the server, not testing.  The `test` script needs to be amended to invoke flow (`"test": "flow"`, plus any other needed option, usually none).  Check the setup instructions for flow for other steps, then run `yarn test`.

Comment: my question is pretty explicit that I was following the guide at:  https://flow.org/en/docs/tools/create-react-app/ and asks what further steps were needed

Comment: I've just given you that.  The linked docs are incomplete, you need to modify the test script to run flow and use an appropriate command line to invoke the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc you linked tells you how to install the flow-bin and to make a configuration file but don`t tells how to launch it.
Flow is separated tool that should be launch by own command (depends on how you wanna run it):

1. if you want to check types check manually, you need to add npm command on the "scripts" section of your `package.js`: `"example-comand-flow": "flow"`. Then call it by `npm run example-comand-flow` and you`ll get errors directly on a terminal you running the script.
2. if you wanna have continuing type checking, you should find a manual how to configure it in your IDE. For example, in WebStorm you should go `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript` and set `JavaScript language version` to `Flow` and specify flow executable.